# No access to "this"

Tags: reactjs, this, undefined, setstate, mern

I'm working on a web-application using the MERN stack that displays a table of clients with their name, email, and phone number. I haven't implemented Redux quite yet, but I'm using 'uuid' to supplement data in the table until I can get the redux store set up. So far I have displaying the the list and adding a client to the list working fine, but I am having trouble with the pesky delete button.

**This is the current ClientTable component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table, Container, Button } from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  getClients,
  addClient,
  editClient,
  deleteClient,
} from "../actions/clientActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const renderClient = (clients, index, id) => {
  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>
        <Button
          className="remove-btn"
          color="danger"
          size="sm"
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState((state) => ({
              clients: state.clients.filter((client) => client.id !== id),
            }));
          }}
        >
          &times;
        </Button>
      </td>
      <td>{clients.name}</td>
      <td>{clients.email}</td>
      <td>{clients.number}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};

class ClientTable extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getClients();
  }

  onDeleteClick = (id) => {
    this.props.deleteClient(id);
  };

  render() {
    const { clients } = this.props.client;
    // const { clients } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container id="listContainer">
        <Table
          id="listTable"
          className="table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
          dark
        >
          <tr class="listRow">
            <thead id="tableHeader">
              <tr>
                <th id="listActions">Actions</th>
                <th id="listName">Name</th>
                <th id="listEmail">Email</th>
                <th id="listNumber">Number</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="listRow">{clients.map(renderClient)}</tbody>
          </tr>
        </Table>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

ClientTable.propTypes = {
  getClients: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  client: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  client: state.client,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getClients,
  deleteClient,
  addClient,
})(ClientTable);
```

**This is the bit of code that is causing me issues**

```
<Button
          className="remove-btn"
          color="danger"
          size="sm"
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState((state) => ({
              clients: state.clients.filter((client) => client.id !== id),
            }));
          }}
        >
          &times;
        </Button>
```

When I click the "delete" button I keep getting ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of unedefined***

I know the error is because of 'this' isn't bound to anything, but I'm uncertain how to bind it within an onClick event if that is even possible or what even to bind it to. I am just lost as to how to approach this problem. (I'm still quite new to React).

If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What did you expect `this` to be in `renderClient`, given that it's not even inside the class?

Comment: @jonrsharpe And as an addition there is no `setState` in function components, instead [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) can be used.

Comment: @norbitrial sure, but `ClientTable` *is* a class component.

Answer (score 0):

move renderClient function to ClientTable, and use it as a method of this class.

```
class ClientTable extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getClients();
  }

  renderClient = (clients, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
       <td>
        <Button
          className="remove-btn"
          color="danger"
          size="sm"
          onClick={() => this.onDeleteClient(clients.id)}
        >
          &times;
        </Button>
      </td>
      <td>{clients.name}</td>
      <td>{clients.email}</td>
      <td>{clients.number}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};


  onDeleteClick = (id) => {
    this.props.deleteClient(id);
  };

  render() {
    const { clients } = this.props.client;
    // const { clients } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container id="listContainer">
        <Table
          id="listTable"
          className="table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
          dark
        >
          <tr class="listRow">
            <thead id="tableHeader">
              <tr>
                <th id="listActions">Actions</th>
                <th id="listName">Name</th>
                <th id="listEmail">Email</th>
                <th id="listNumber">Number</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="listRow">{clients.map(this.renderClient)}</tbody>
          </tr>
        </Table>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solved my "this" problem, but now 'clients' is coming up undefined.

Comment: as I see from your code, you get clients from redux, also you connect deleteClient action, so try to use it(example updated)

Comment: one more, the third param in map cb is array,